# AngularJS JavaScript for loop warning that will run at most once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webstorm

Why does WebStorm warn me that my `for` loop will only run at most once?

```
if (data[i].name) {
    for (var j = 0; j < data[i].name.length; j++) {
        hobby = $scope.users[data[i].name].hobby;
        sport = $scope.users[data[i].name].sport;
        education = $scope.users[data[i].name].education;
        break;
    }
}
```

Where is the problem? What am I missing here?

Comment: You have a `break;` at the end of the loop, that will make the execution exit the loop after one pass.

Comment: @rakemen thanks it fixes it

Comment: @rakemen isn't my `j` redundant? or is it needed indeed?

Comment: `j` is not redundant, `j` is needed to loop inside the `for` `data[i].name.length` times. But since u have a `break` there at the end, the entire `for` loop seems redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the loop is only executed once at most since you `break` the execution after the first iteration.

However, from looking at the code, you may not need a loop here at all. It seems like all you want to do is check whether the string `data[i].name` is set, and if so, retrieve some properties based on that, correct?

If so, remove the loop, as it does not contribute anything to the posted snippet:

```
if (data[i].name) {
    hobby = $scope.users[data[i].name].hobby;
    sport = $scope.users[data[i].name].sport;
    education = $scope.users[data[i].name].education;
}
```

Assuming that `data[i].name` is a string, `data[i].name.length` will only give you the length of the string.